# jQuery Appending an Object multiple times

Tags: jquery, variables, object, append

I am not sure what exactly is happening here, I think the fact that the variable is a jquery object.

This only appends once, my question is why?

```
var newInput = $('<input/>');
$('#newDiv').append(newInput);
$('#newDiv').append(newInput);
```

Though this works as I would assume

```
var newInput = '<input>';
$('#newDiv').append(newInput);
$('#newDiv').append(newInput);
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you do `$('<input/>')`, jQuery creates an `input` DOM element for you.

When you `.append()` a DOM element, it detaches the element from its previous position. [(See Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/c0svfz3m/). From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location
>   elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned).

Thus, your second `.append()` call will remove it from where it was appended first and place it in the new position.

When you append a string, the DOM element is created as it is appended.

Comment: Oh my, I had no idea that is how it worked. Thank you for setting me straight.

Comment: "When you append a string, the DOM element is created after it is appended." This statement makes no sense...

Comment: @plalx Ah, sorry. Thanks for pointing that out, I tried to fix it.

Comment: upvoted. official documentation link is also required.

Answer (score 24):

In the first case, `$` will parse your html and create a new jQuery object which will wrap over an `HTMLInputElement`.

Basically, it's like doing:

```
var $newDiv = $('#newDiv'),
    newInput = document.createElement('input');

$newDiv.append(newInput);
$newDiv.append(newInput);
```

In the second case, it's parsing the html every time, generating a different jQuery object for every instance.

Here's how the first sample could be fixed:

```
var newInput = $('<input/>');
$('#newDiv').append(newInput);
$('#newDiv').append(newInput.clone());
```

Comment: upvoted. official documentation link is also required.

Answer (score 1):

It is because in the first case it is referring to the same element **object** (appends same element so it's appended to new place), and in second case you are appending html as string so it appends multiple elements (new element every time).

Answer (score 1):

You can append multiple elements by creating new element each time with loop:

```js
(function(){
  for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    var newInput = $('<input>');
    $('#newDiv').append(newInput);
}})();
```

```css
input {border:1px solid red; margin:3px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `append` method actually moves the element so, if you check this code in debugger with different div tags you will see the element will be created once and then moved to next div in your case it is being moved to same div. To solve this you can use the `clone` method in  to create a new clone of the element every time you  append it.

example HTML :

```
<div id="hello">
  
</div>
```

JS :

```
function addToDiv(div,data){
  $('#'+div).append(data)
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  let temp = $('<p>').html('hello')
  addToDiv('hello',temp.clone());
  addToDiv('hello',temp.clone());

});
```