# jQuery Append only adding 1 item

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm trying to make jQuery append a div to the body of my document multiple times, but for some reason its only appending one item and I'm guessing its the last item in the loop.

```js
$(function(){
  var howManyParticles = 11;
  var bodyWidth = $(document).width();
  var randomSpawn = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyWidth) + 1;
  var particleStyle = "background: lightgray;width: 10px;height: 10px;min-height: 10px;min-width: 10px;position: fixed;bottom: 0;left:" + randomSpawn + ";";
  var particle = $("<div class='particle' style='"+ particleStyle +"'>&nbsp;</div>");

  function spawnParticles(){
    for(var i = 0; i <= howManyParticles; i++)
    {
      $('body').append(particle);
      console.log('spawned');
    }
  }

  spawnParticles();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This only spawns 1 item to the window, how do i make it so it spawns as many items as `i <= howManyParticles` is going to be?

EDIT: My Final Code

I forgot that i need to put the `math.random` function within the loop to give a different horizontal value to each different particle that was spawned!

```
$(function(){
    var howManyParticles = 11;
    var bodyWidth = $(document).width();

    function spawnParticles(){
        for(var i = 0; i <= howManyParticles; i++)
        {
            var randomSpawn = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyWidth) + 1;
            var particleStyle = "background: lightgray;width: 10px;height: 10px;min-height: 10px;min-width: 10px;position: fixed;bottom: 0;left:" + randomSpawn + ";";
            var particle = $("<div class='particle' style='"+ particleStyle +"'>&nbsp;</div>");
            $('body').append(particle);

        }
    }

    spawnParticles();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some cases where jQuery automatically clones a node for you, and others where it does not. In this case it does not because it thinks you're actually trying to just relocate a node.

Instead of creating the DOM element in advance, create it in the loop.

```js
$(function(){
  var howManyParticles = 11;
  var bodyWidth = $(document).width();
  var randomSpawn = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyWidth) + 1;
  var particleStyle = "float: left; background: orange; border:1px solid red; width: 10px; height: 10px; margin: 5px;";

  // Just a string------v
  var particle = "<div class='particle' style='"+ particleStyle +"'>&nbsp;</div>";

  function spawnParticles(){
      for(var i = 0; i <= howManyParticles; i++)
      {
 // Append the string, which is turned into a new DOM element on each iteration
          $('body').append(particle);
          console.log('spawned');
      }
  }

  spawnParticles();

console.log("FOUND %s PARTICLES", document.querySelectorAll(".particle").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Im sure i've done it how you said to but its still doing the same thing, just appending a single node

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius: I updated the demo to show that it creates and finds 12 particles. Remember that your CSS has them sitting nearly on top of each other.

Comment: This is great thanks helped me find the source to the problem, I needed to put the `math.random` function within the loop as well so that it equalled to a different value each time, that was my bad but thanks so much this works!

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius: That makes sense. :)

Answer (score 2):

You've to clone the element everytime you want to add it since you cant append the same element several times :

```
$('body').append(particle.clone());
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function(){
  var howManyParticles = 11;
  var bodyWidth = $(document).width();
  var randomSpawn = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyWidth) + 1;
  var particleStyle = "left:" + randomSpawn + "px;";
  var particle = $("<div class='particle' style='"+ particleStyle +"'>&nbsp;</div>");

  function spawnParticles(){
    for(var i = 0; i <= howManyParticles; i++)
    {
      $('body').append(particle.clone());
    }
  }

  spawnParticles();
});
```

```css
.particle{
  background: lightgray;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
  min-width: 10px;
  bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Random `left` for every div :**

```js
$(function(){
  var howManyParticles = 11;
  var bodyWidth = $(document).width();


  function spawnParticles(){
    for(var i = 0; i <= howManyParticles; i++)
    {
      var randomSpawn = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyWidth) + 1;
      var particleStyle = "left:" + randomSpawn + "px;";
      var particle = $("<div class='particle' style='"+ particleStyle +"'>&nbsp;</div>");

      $('body').append(particle);
    }
  }

  spawnParticles();
});
```

```css
.particle{
  background: lightgray;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
  min-width: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, I've tried that clone() function but it doesn't act any differently

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki: Adding `.html()` doesn't make a difference, except that it serializes and discards the cloned element and then parses the HTML and recreates a new one when `.append()` gets the HTML. So it's just more work for no difference.

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius that related with the style you've added to the element, you could see the element appended without style, check my snippet.

Comment: Thanks @squint for your intervention, it was a css of the div who make it not visible on the body.

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius you've to remove the position fixed and to add `px` to the `left` style, check my update.

Comment: Yeah, the CSS had me confused at first.

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius If you want random left style for every div check my update.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is that you create ONE node when you do

```
 var particle = $("<div class='particle' style=''>&nbsp; Particle div</div>");
```

As referenced in other Stack Overflow questions, like this one:

[jQuery Appending an Object multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939472/jquery-appending-an-object-multiple-times)

You just have **ONE** html node and you are appending it to the body multiple times in the loop, so is actually the same node being deleted and moved in the DOM. If you want multiple nodes, you should clone the element like

```
$('body').append(particle.clone());
```

just as other anwsers tell you.Other option is to instantiate the node inside loop, just like this:

```
$(function(){
var howManyParticles = 11;
var bodyWidth = $(document).width();
var randomSpawn = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyWidth) + 1;
var particleStyle = "background: lightgray;width: 10px;height: 10px;min-height: 10px;min-width: 10px;position: fixed;bottom: 0;left:" + randomSpawn + ";";


function spawnParticles(){
    for(var i = 0; i <= howManyParticles; i++)
    {
        var particle = $("<div class='particle' style='"+ particleStyle +"'>&nbsp;</div>");
        $('body').append(particle);
        console.log('spawned');
    }
}

spawnParticles();
});
```

Hope it helps :)